# how can we put different value while embedding selector in other component in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, components, routerlink

I have around 300 components and I am adding embedding one common menu html, and I want to change url value with unique value.

here is my files:

**common.menu.component.html**

```
<div class="packages-menu">
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let allPkgs of packages; let i = index;" routerLinkActive="active">
            <a routerLink="/nepal-package-{{i+startingNight}}n" class="packages-link" title="{{allPkgs.title}}">{{allPkgs.title}} </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to change **`routerLink`** value while embedding in other component

**common.menu.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'packages-menu',
    templateUrl: './common.menu.component.html',
    providers:[PackagesServices]
})
```

**other.component.ts**
 while embedding it I am passing data-val to get different value.

```
<packages-menu data-val="different value"></packages-menu>
 <div class="hti-modrentitle">
     <h1>{{pkg.title}}</h1>
 </div>
```

I want to put `**data-val**` value in **`routerLink`** so I can have different url for all components.

Is that possible or any other way to do it. Please help